# CakePHP cms tutorial missing Helpers

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Just starting with CakePHP and started the cms tutorial.

Install and configure went fine, but when I get to load the site for the first time there is a missing HTML Helper error.

When checking the View/Helper directory, it is empty: so obviously not installed.

What do I need to do to get the Helpers installed?

Comment: The HTML helper is part of the CakePHP framework core, it would be located in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/View/Helper/`. That being said, please always post **the _complete_ error**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion). Also make sure that you have debug mode enabled, and if you receive a detailed error page, include a screenshot of it, it might have additional info that helps to identify/solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks ndm. Yes, I thought/realised it should have been part of core, but after installing via Composer (as per directions) the Helper directory (eg: C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\src\View\Helper\) has a single file of 0 length called **Empty**. This happened both for the cms tutorial and installing the 'app' template. When I check on Git, the Helper directory in the app project is empty too. I didn't know if I needed to change the Composer settings or download separately?

Comment: You are looking at the wrong place, check the directory that I've mentioned, that is where the core helpers are located, you are looking in your applications helper directory, which is by default empty (the zero byte file is there so that Git can track the empty directory).

Comment: You are absolutely correct, thank you... the actual problem was a stray character in the code (which led me down the wrong Helper path). Oh well: lots of lessons learned :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was incorrect code in the ctp file (a stray character), and I incorrectly read the Error message as a missing Helper.

Core Helper was not actually missing, I just needed to read the Directory to discover the difference between core helpers and application helpers :-/